# Документация проектов C# на нескольких языках в VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, документация

Необходимо задокументировать весь код в проекте, чтобы при использовании метода, студия подсказывала о нём всё, что только можно. Единственное, что я смог найти для своей ситуации - это **XML документация, для .csproj**. Но, насколько я понял, это получается не слишком красиво и очень громоздко в исходниках, тем более, если делать через **xml:lang="LANG_ID"**.

Какой подход наиболее хороший и правильный, для документирования кода?
В конечном итоге, конечно, хотелось бы достичь такого результата, как у .NET из коробки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE #1**

Сейчас мне пришла в голову очень странная идея, для моей задачи, мне нужна просто документация для какой-то DLL на разных языках и всё. Думаю написать какое-нибудь ПО, которое будет подниматься на **prebuild событии** и выставлять везде где нужно документацию, чтобы студия собрала XML файл. А на **postbuild событии** будет подниматься ПО, которое будет очищать все выставленные строчки. **Этот подход позволить сделать код чистым от доки и полностью автоматизировать процесс** (только саму доку придется править).

Answer (score 4):

Не хочу расстроить, но `XML-комментарии`, это то единственное, что позволит вам достичь желаемого результата. А для того чтобы процесс их написания не был таким "болезненным" и скучным, от себя могу порекомендовать расширение для `Visual Studio` под названием [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), которое позволяет автоматизировать и стандартизировать некоторые рутинные действия и операции.

Comment: За экстеншен спасибо, неплохой! :-) Заапдейтил пост, пришло в голову неплохое решение

Comment: Если вы заметили, там есть как платные, так и бесплатные версии, но даже бесплатная позволяет переопределять заданные производителем комментарии на свой лад и вкус, что весьма экономит время в дальнейшем )