# Как написать подсказку(определение?) в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Как мне сделать вот такую подсказку в своем методе?
Как тут.
[image: pic1]

Вот мой метод, как добавить туда где красная линия мой текст?

[image: pic2]

Comment: Введите '///' и нажмите `tab`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684613/182750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из [руководства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary)

```
        /// <summary>Описание пиши здесь
        /// <para>Здесь можно ввести второй параграф описания<see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> для большей информации</para>
        /// <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>
        /// </summary>
```